# Android app Address family not supported by protocol error?

Tags: android

my code:

private static final String TAG = "TextToSpeechDemo";

```
private TextToSpeech mTts;
private Button mAgainButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.speak);


TextToSpeech mTts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
 // Initialize text-to-speech. This is an asynchronous operation.
// The OnInitListener (second argument) is called after initialization completes.
mTts = new TextToSpeech(this,
    this  // TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
    );

// The button is disabled in the layout.
// It will be enabled upon initialization of the TTS engine.
mAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.again_button);

mAgainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sayHello();
    }
});


@Override
public void onInit( int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // status can be either TextToSpeech.SUCCESS or TextToSpeech.ERROR.
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
    // Set preferred language to US english.
    // Note that a language may not be available, and the result will indicate this.
    int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    // Try this someday for some interesting results.
    // int result mTts.setLanguage(Locale.FRANCE);
    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
    result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
    // Language data is missing or the language is not supported.
    Log.e(TAG, "Language is not available.");
    } else {
    // Check the documentation for other possible result codes.
    // For example, the language may be available for the locale,
    // but not for the specified country and variant.
    // The TTS engine has been successfully initialized.
    // Allow the user to press the button for the app to speak again.
    mAgainButton.setEnabled(true);
    // Greet the user.
    sayHello();
}
    }
    else {
        // Initialization failed.
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not initialize TextToSpeech.");
        }
        }
private void sayHello() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    String filename = extras.getString("filename");
    String filecontent = extras.getString("filecontent");
    mTts.speak(filecontent,
    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
    null);
    }
```

it is showing 03-03 12:01:21.778: D/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol error!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a guess at this. I think, `String filename = extras.getString("filename");` should be changed to `String filename = extras.getString("file://" + "filename");`

Please post relevant `logcat` output to help everyone understand the problem.

Comment: still the same error log cat:03-03 12:20:04.347: D/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: nw its showing:03-03 12:24:22.106: W/KeyCharacterMap(413): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
and 03-03 12:24:22.106: W/KeyCharacterMap(413): No keyboard for id 0

Comment: I just changed it to `file://`
Sorry for the typo. Please see if this works.